# Tagging images used for search bar

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm working with a classmate to build some kind of politicaly-related memes database where users will have the ability to tag images with hashtags, using Meteor. The purpose of this, beyond data collection, is to provide a powerful search engine, where one can find memes with keywords (let's say, for i.e., with the keywords "ukraine" and/or "poutine", you'll find memes related to theses topics) that matches the hashtags.

We have to build everything from scratch, and I'm wondering if someone here have an idea where to start. In other words :

- What is the easiest way to host images with Meteor ? Is it through MangoDB ?
- Is it possible to change the metadata of the images in the client side ? Do we need to grant this ability using javascript only (or is there also json in it) ?
- If we can manage the two first parts, is there a way to link the metadata (the hashtags in that case) with the search engine in order to retrieve the images ?

Thank you for inputs !

Answer (score 0):

- It's not easiest but I would store images in Google Cloud Storage or Amazon S3
- I would store image metadata in mongodb database. You can update the database from client side by calling Meteor Methods
- When users search for images by entering keywords or link with keywords, you can query the database then return the related images.

Comment: FYI the question itself is off-topic (tool/product recommendations, opinions). Please don't answer these - they often lead to spam and debate. Also, you're suggesting two of many cloud solutions, and one of dozens of databases; there is no specific reason to use mongodb vs many other databases (aside from Meteor's use of MongoDB). There is just no possible way to answer such a question objectively.

Comment: @DavidMakogon : in fact, no matter how vague the question was, the answer is a good start : I didn't knew we could host pictures and metadata in two different databases.

Comment: @DavidMakogon. I know they are NOT only cloud solutions, but I used them and have good experience. The question is about using Meteor. It uses MongoDB. There is no reason to use another database.